# Java Thermal Printer printing QRCode with Text

Tags: java, qr-code, thermal-printer

I am new to Java printing and wanted to to print a `QRCode` with a small number under it on a Thermal Printer `(Brother QL-810W)`.

With my code I can print my `QRCode`, but I cannot figure out how to print a number or text, also I can't use `ESC/P Commands` for formatting.
I tried using ByteArrays and `escpos-coffe` library but it won't work.

Code:

```
try {
  DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
  PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

  aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
  aset.add(MediaSizeName.INVOICE);
  PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
  for (PrintService printService: services) {
    if (printService.getName().equals("Brother QL-810W")) {
      DocPrintJob pj = printService.createPrintJob();
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Local/QRCode1.png");
      Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
      pj.print(doc, aset);
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}

}
```

Heres the code I tried to work with the `escpos-coffe` libary:

```
    try {
      PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
      for (PrintService printService: services) {
        if (printService.getName().equals("Brother QL-810W")) {
          PrinterOutputStream printerOutputStream = new PrinterOutputStream(printService);
          EscPos escpos = new EscPos(printerOutputStream);
          escpos.writeLF("1235");
          escpos.feed(5);
          escpos.cut(EscPos.CutMode.FULL);
          escpos.close();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: As you wrote, Brother label printers operate on ESC/P, and there are many parts that are not compatible with ESC/POS. It seems better to look for other libraries instead of [escpos-coffee](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee). How about an article like this? [pklaus/brother_ql - Related and Unrelated Software.md](https://gist.github.com/pklaus/aeb55e18d36690df6a84a3eab49e9fd7)

Comment: I did look up those libraries, but the one for java didn't work either the problem is I don't get any error messages the printer just doesn't do anything. I found this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573466/printer-doesnt-work-receiving-esc-p-commands), but it doesn't help. But thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: By the way, 2D barcodes such as QR codes do not have specifications for printing human readable interpretation like 1D barcodes. The printer will not have such a function. If you want to print a string of QR code content near the QR code, you can simply print the text of that content.